# moviepy enlarging and zooming in video outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy, video-editing

I'm new to moviepy my requirement is to make a normal video into 2x. All the videos are recorded on the phone and the videos which are not required any rotations are working fine. By the videos which are needed to be rotated even, I apply rotation or even just trying to write the outup is zoomed in with full screen here is the code

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

```
from moviepy.audio import *

import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx

clip = VideoFileClip("testingggg.mp4",audio=False) 

clip.size

#clip = clip.rotate(90) 

print("Duration of video : ", clip.duration)

print("Duration of video : ", clip.reader.fps)

clip = clip.speedx(2)

#clip = VideoFileClip("final.mp4",audio=False) 

#clip.size

clip.write_videofile("final.mp4", threads=4, audio_fps=44100,codec = 'libx264')
```

hope someone can help me here are some images so that u can get an idea on my issue image of original file output is in this way

original
[image]

output
[image]

Thank you